# Is lock only for multi-thread programming?

Tags: javascript, c#, thread-safety, locking, interpreter

JavaScript is single thread and there is no locking syntax there. For other languages like C# or Java which allow multi-thread programming, they have locking mechanisms. But internally does the JavaScript interpreter has some locking mechanism to make sure the operations are atomic?

Comment: `JavaScript is single thread`

Comment: atomic != single threaded

Answer (score 1):

No. Javascript does not support multi-thread because the browser interprets javascript in a single thread (AFAIK). However you can force concurrency using a while loop with a flag and setTimeout to left the processor to another process.